# Indenting equations

Tags: indentation, amsmath

I'm using `amsmath[fleqn]` but I'd like to also indent equations outside equation/align/gather environments. A natural choice would be to indent using the same length `amsmath` uses, but I don't know how to do that. I've tried to use `\mathindent` (without defining its value) but it gives a "missing number" error. How should I do this? Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Especially how do you produce these equations outside of align/gather environments?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you mean by wanting to "indent equations outside [of] equation/align/gather environments"? What kind of equations do you have in mind -- those encased by `\[` and `\]` statements? Or, expressions given in "inline" math mode (delimited by `$` signs, or `\(` and `\)` pairs)? Please edit/augment your posting to tell us a bit more about the material you want to indent.

Comment: Would `\setlength{\mathindent}{<length>}` do?

Answer (score 3):

`\mathindent` holds a length, so to "use it", it would have to be done as `\hspace{\mathindent}`, say. Here's perhaps an example of what might be of interest:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
Some text before the equation.
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
\end{equation}
Some text after the equation.

\hspace*{\dimexpr\mathindent-\parindent}$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$

Some more text before an equation.
\[
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
\]
Some more text after an equation.
\end{document}
```

Note that unnumbered equations are possible without the need for manual indentation. You could just use the starred version of `align`, say.